# Monopoly Deal question

Tags: monopoly-deal

I used a Forced Deal to exchange my Wildcard for a Green property. I placed my Wildcard on my opponents Boardwalk and then used my Deal Breaker to take that set. Was that a legal move?

Comment: You don't get to choose which set their property goes in.

Comment: Exactly! So how is the wildcard placement decided then?

Comment: Why would you expect anybody except the owner of the property to place it?

Comment: I would guess that the rules say the owner chooses the placement in order to prevent someone from playing that card, making a set and stealing it with another card like you did.

Answer (score 1):

No, this was not legal,unless your opponent willingly chose to place the Wildcard on their Boardwalk. From the [official FAQ](https://monopolydealrules.com/index.php?page=property):

> Can you move Property Wildcards already on the table around to different Monopoly property sets?
>
> > Yes, a player can move wild cards around as many times as they want as long as it is done during their turn. Once their turn is over, they cannot move their cards around. The only exception is **when a player plays a Force Deal card and swaps one of your properties, then you can arrange the new property in your property section accordingly**.

So your opponent would get to choose where they wanted the wild card, not you.

Comment: I guess that answers the question. So even if it was not my opponents turn, they get to decide where the Wildcard gets placed, thus defeating my Deal Breaker gambit. Thanks!